# Implicitly passing a list’s current element to a function using map

Tags: python, multithreading

I’m trying to speed up directory bruteforcing by using multithreading.

```
def enumerate_http(hostname, wordlist='/root/common.txt'):
    directory_list = []

    with open(wordlist, 'r') as wordlist_file:
        [directory_list.append(directory) for directory in wordlist_file.read lines()]

    with Pool(thread_count) as p:
        results = p.map(check_directory, directory_list)
```

The problem is that the `check_directory(hostname, directory)` function needs to take the directory_list’s current element as a parameter in addition to another parameter. How can I explicitly pass the first parameter, and implicitly pass the current element to the function’s parameter?

Comment: why are you using a list comprehension as a side effect product? Please don't do that...

Comment: @MooingRawr Would you mind elaborating on as to why a list comprehension is bad in this context to add elements to a list?

Comment: It is frowned upon to use a list comprehension or generator expression just for the side effects - it what you do when you are not assigning the expression for later use or iterating over it: you are interested only in the side effects and not in the result for the l.c. or g.e. Make it a plain `for` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a partial function specific to your host name:

```
from functools import partial

check_directory_host = partial(check_directory, hostname=hostname)

with Pool(thread_count) as p:
    results = p.map(check_directory_host, directory_list)
```

[partial](http://%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) creates a new function with the argument `hostname` "fixed":

> `partial(func, *args, **keywords)` - new function with partial application
>   of the given arguments and keywords.

Here an example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add_10 = partial(add, b=10)
```

Now the second argument `b` is fixed and you can (and must) call the function only with a value for `a`:

```
>>> add_10(5)
15
```